# Magento 2: Product Image Watermark Size Not Changing

Tags: magento2, product-images, watermark

Magento 2: I want to change watermark image size but change is not reflecting on the product view page.

Comment: you have flush catalog product images cache ??

Comment: Yes flush catalog product image cache and refresh all cache but not work